# Encrypt & decrypt URL parameters in spring

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I would like to encrypt URL GET parameters that all links will be something like below.

Encrypted in html:

```
home.htm?ecryptParam=aajsbjabsjvyhasyayasy
```

Actual:

```
home.htm?fName=samir&lName=vora
```

At the same time, in controller class it will have the decrypted value automatically and I can retrieve it from request. e.g.:

Link:

```
home.htm?ecrypt=SKJIIU86iuGkJGkJFHGBVBVn
```

Controller class:
`request.getParameter("fName");` will return samir

Comment: dont't do the heavylifting, use https and request and response will be encrypted and decrypted by the server.

Comment: ok then tell how it's work give me example but how can we will possible like this

Comment: Google how to configure https on <server you are using>

Answer (score 0):

Samir, If you passing value as encrypt format in url and you will retrieve using request param as encrypt format, and you will need to decrypt those values for that please refer this link "http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html". It might help.

Answer (score 0):

While you really should handle security backend, simple text obfuscation can be easily achived in JavaScript.

Here is an example:

```js
//Encrypter class
var stringEncrypter = (function() {
  function stringEncrypter() {}
  stringEncrypter.encrypt = function(str) {
    str = str.toString();
    var returnCode = [];
    for (var strIndex = 0; strIndex < str.length; strIndex++) {
      var element = str[strIndex];
      //Push with bitwise offset (or remove the bitwise offset here and in decrypt)
      returnCode.push(element.charCodeAt(0) << this.off);
    }
    //return a joined string
    return returnCode.join(this.splitter);
  };
  stringEncrypter.decrypt = function(str) {
    var list = str.split(this.splitter);
    var returnCode = "";
    for (var strIndex = 0; strIndex < list.length; strIndex++) {
      var element = list[strIndex];
      //Push with bitwise offset (or remove the bitwise offset here and in encrypt)
      returnCode += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(element) >> this.off);
    }
    return returnCode;
  };
  stringEncrypter.encryptUrl = function(url) {
    if (url.substr(url.indexOf("?") >= 0)) {
      var str = url.substr(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
      if (str.lastIndexOf("#") >= 0) {
        str = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf("#"));
      }
      var params = str.split("&");
      for (var paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < params.length; paramIndex++) {
        var param = params[paramIndex].split("=");
        param[0] = this.encrypt(param[0]);
        param[1] = this.encrypt(param[1]);
        params[paramIndex] = param.join("=");
      }
      url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf("?") + 1) + params.join("&") +
        (url.lastIndexOf("#") >= 0 ? url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("#")) : "");
    }
    return url;
  };
  stringEncrypter.decryptUrl = function(url) {
    if (url.substr(url.indexOf("?") >= 0)) {
      var str = url.substr(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
      if (str.lastIndexOf("#") >= 0) {
        str = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf("#"));
      }
      var params = str.split("&");
      for (var paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < params.length; paramIndex++) {
        var param = params[paramIndex].split("=");
        param[0] = this.decrypt(param[0]);
        param[1] = this.decrypt(param[1]);
        params[paramIndex] = param.join("=");
      }
      url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf("?") + 1) + params.join("&") +
        (url.lastIndexOf("#") >= 0 ? url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("#")) : "");
    }
    return url;
  };
  return stringEncrypter;
}());
//Bitwise offset. Completely optional
stringEncrypter.off = 2;
stringEncrypter.splitter = "|";
//Encrypt a string
console.log(stringEncrypter.encrypt("Testing123"));
//Decrypt a string
console.log(stringEncrypter.decrypt(stringEncrypter.encrypt("Testing123")));
//Decrypt a url
console.log(stringEncrypter.encryptUrl("www.test.dk?test=45"));
//Encrypt a url
console.log(stringEncrypter.decryptUrl(stringEncrypter.encryptUrl("www.test.dk?test=45")));
//Decrypt a url with #
console.log(stringEncrypter.encryptUrl("www.test.dk?test=45#title1"));
//Encrypt a url with #
console.log(stringEncrypter.decryptUrl(stringEncrypter.encryptUrl("www.test.dk?test=45#title1")));
```